# How to allow user to choose a colour for data being input in canvas 2d

Tags: html, canvas, graphics, html5-canvas

I have code that generates barcharts where the user chooses the value of the bars. At present, the colours of these bars have been hard coded to alternate between red and blue. What I'd like help with is how to allow the user to choose the colour of each bar as they set the value. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Here's what I've got so far;

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>

var barVals = [];

function draw() {

  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  // calculate highest bar value (used to scale the rest)
  var highest = 0;
  for (var b = 0; b < barVals.length; b++) {
    if (barVals[b] > highest)
      highest = barVals[b];
  }

  // we have 8 horizontal lines so calculate an appropriate scale

  var lineSpacing = 1;
  var highestLine = 7 * lineSpacing;

  while (highestLine < highest) {
    lineSpacing *= 10;
    highestLine = 7 * lineSpacing;
  }



  // grey background

  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(200,200,200)";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 600, 450);



  // draw and (if we have any data to scale from) label horizontal lines

  var lineNum = 0;
  ctx.fillStyle = "white";
  ctx.font = "16px sans-serif";
  for (y = 0; y <= 350; y += 50) {

    // line
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(50, y + 50);
    ctx.lineTo(550, y + 50);
    ctx.stroke();

    // label (the 6 is an offset to centre the text vertically on the line)

    if (barVals.length > 0) {
      ctx.fillText(lineSpacing * lineNum, 10, 400 - y + 6);
      lineNum++;

    }
  }



  // draw boxes (widths based on how many we have)

  var barWidth = 500 / barVals.length;
  var halfBarWidth = barWidth / 2;
  for (b = 0; b < barVals.length; b++) {

    // calculate size of box and draw it

    var x = 60 + b * barWidth;
    var hgt = (barVals[b] / highestLine) * 350; // as fraction of highest line

    if (b % 2 == 0)
      ctx.fillStyle = "red";

    else

      ctx.fillStyle = "blue";

    ctx.fillRect(x, 400 - hgt, barWidth, hgt);

    // calculate position of text and draw it

    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    var metrics = ctx.measureText(barVals[b]);
    var halfTextWidth = metrics.width / 2;
    x = 60 + halfBarWidth + (b * barWidth) - halfTextWidth;
    ctx.fillText(barVals[b], x, 420 - hgt);

  }

}



function addBar() {

  var textBoxObj = document.getElementById("barVal");
  barVals.push(parseInt(textBoxObj.value)); // add new value to end of array. As an integer not a string!!
  draw(); // redraw

  textBoxObj.value = 0;

}

function removeBar() {

  var textBoxObj = document.getElementById("removeBarVal");
  barVals.splice(parseInt(textBoxObj.value), 1); // choose which object to remove from the array by specifying the index
  draw(); // redraw
    
}
    
function editBar() {
    
    var textBoxObj = document.getElementById("editBarVal");
    barVals.replace(parseInt(textBoxObj.value), 1);
    draw(); // redraw
}
    

</script>
</head>


                                 
<body onload="draw()";                           
<center>
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="450"></canvas>
<form>
<br>
<input type=button value='Add Bar' onclick='addBar();'> <input id='barVal' value=0>
<input type="color" id="favcolor" name="favcolor" value="#ff0000"><input type=button value="Submit" onclick="addBar();">  
<input type=button value='Remove Bar' onclick='removeBar();'> <input id='removeBarVal' value=0>
<input type=button value='Edit Bar' onclick='editBar();'> <input id='editBarVal' value=0>

  </form>
</center>
```

Answer (score 0):

It won't probabily be exactly what you are looking for but if you want to do it yourself you could use a range input

all you need to do is to add an eventListener (onchange) and get the value of your color input field to store it in a variable (or pass it to the function) and then use this variable to set the ctx.fillStyle

```
favcolor.onchange=(e)=>{
  mycolor=e.target.value;
}
```

```js
var barVals = [];
let mycolor = "rgb(200,200,200)";

function draw() {
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  // calculate highest bar value (used to scale the rest)
  var highest = 0;
  for (var b = 0; b < barVals.length; b++) {
    if (barVals[b] > highest)
      highest = barVals[b];
  }

  // we have 8 horizontal lines so calculate an appropriate scale

  var lineSpacing = 1;
  var highestLine = 7 * lineSpacing;

  while (highestLine < highest) {
    lineSpacing *= 10;
    highestLine = 7 * lineSpacing;
  }



  // grey background

  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(200,200,200)";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 600, 450);



  // draw and (if we have any data to scale from) label horizontal lines

  var lineNum = 0;
  ctx.fillStyle = "white";
  ctx.font = "16px sans-serif";
  for (y = 0; y <= 350; y += 50) {

    // line
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(50, y + 50);
    ctx.lineTo(550, y + 50);
    ctx.stroke();

    // label (the 6 is an offset to centre the text vertically on the line)

    if (barVals.length > 0) {
      ctx.fillText(lineSpacing * lineNum, 10, 400 - y + 6);
      lineNum++;

    }
  }



  // draw boxes (widths based on how many we have)

  var barWidth = 500 / barVals.length;
  var halfBarWidth = barWidth / 2;
  for (b = 0; b < barVals.length; b++) {

    // calculate size of box and draw it

    var x = 60 + b * barWidth;
    var hgt = (barVals[b] / highestLine) * 350; // as fraction of highest line

      ctx.fillStyle = mycolor

    ctx.fillRect(x, 400 - hgt, barWidth, hgt);

    // calculate position of text and draw it

    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    var metrics = ctx.measureText(barVals[b]);
    var halfTextWidth = metrics.width / 2;
    x = 60 + halfBarWidth + (b * barWidth) - halfTextWidth;
    ctx.fillText(barVals[b], x, 420 - hgt);

  }

}



function addBar() {

  var textBoxObj = document.getElementById("barVal");
  barVals.push(parseInt(textBoxObj.value)); // add new value to end of array. As an integer not a string!!
  draw(); // redraw

  textBoxObj.value = 0;

}

function removeBar() {

  var textBoxObj = document.getElementById("removeBarVal");
  barVals.splice(parseInt(textBoxObj.value), 1); // choose which object to remove from the array by specifying the index
  draw(); // redraw
    
}
    
function editBar() {
    
    var textBoxObj = document.getElementById("editBarVal");
    barVals.replace(parseInt(textBoxObj.value), 1);
    draw(); // redraw
}

favcolor.onchange=(e)=>{
  mycolor=e.target.value;
}
```

```html
<body onload="draw()";                           
<center>
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="450"></canvas>
<form>
<br>
<input type=button value='Add Bar' onclick='addBar();'> <input id='barVal' value=0>
<input type="color" id="favcolor" name="favcolor" value="#ff0000"><input type=button value="Submit" onclick="addBar();">  
<input type=button value='Remove Bar' onclick='removeBar();'> <input id='removeBarVal' value=0>
<input type=button value='Edit Bar' onclick='editBar();'> <input id='editBarVal' value=0>

  </form>
</center>
```

in the other cases you can use javascript extensions who helps you to choose an hsl or rgb color